# Merging two similar code pieces together in Python

Tags: python

I am quite new to python, and have a problem with a code I am currently working on. As you can see in the bit of my code below, it is basically identical to each other, the only thing that separates the two is the `player/opponentTile`, I would like to merge these two together but I don't exactly know how. Any advice is appreciated! ( I cannot only put `if self.legalMove(playerTile, opponentTile, x, y) == False:`).

And I would also not like having both `self, playerTile, opponentTile` in the `def ....Move` considering I want to call onto the definition in the code only using for example: `playerMove(playerTile)` (And if I do that a ValueError pop up)

```
def playerMove(self,playerTile):
    if self.legalMove(playerTile, x, y) == False:
        continue
    else:
        break

def opponentMove(self,opponentTile):
    if self.legalMove(opponentTile, x, y) == False:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: But these are *exactly* the same. The only difference is what you named the argument you passed in, but Python doesn't care what you call it. Just name it "tile".

Comment: The thing is that I need to use the two tiles separate, whilst in the ending counting the scores of the opponenttile and the playertile. Would it still work if I dont define playerTile and opponentTile? @DanielRoseman

Comment: Yes. The difference is what you pass to it, not what it's called inside the method.

Comment: Yeah Ive solved it now

Answer (score 3):

These methods seem to be exactly the same. You only need one.

Rename it to:

```
def move(self, tile)
```

and you can use it in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the same you only have to pass the entity you want to move

```
def entity_move(self,entity_tile): 
    possibilities = '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split()
    while True:
        move = input().lower()
        if len(move) == 2 and move[0] in possibilities and move[1] in possibilities:
            x = int(move[0])
            y = int(move[1])
            if self.legalMove(entity_tile, x, y) == False:
                continue
            else:
                break
        else:
            print('Not a valid input!')
```